# How to make Login using redux in react js

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am creating login concept using redux in react.js I am getting an error -  Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in 
{this.props.userlogin.name}

I have created action and reducer in code.

My header.js File is -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Header.css'
import logo from '../logo.png';
import LoadingSpinner from '../loadingspinner.component';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import { loginUser } from "../../Actions/actions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const emailRegex = RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/)

const formValid = formErrors => {
    let valid = true;
    Object.values(formErrors).forEach(val => {
        val.length > 0 && (valid = false)
    });
    return valid;
}

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            show: false,
            email: "",
            name: "",
            password: "",
            loading: false,
            message: '',
            formErrors: {
                email: "",
                password: ""
            }
        };

        this.handleShow = () => {
            this.setState({ show: true });
        };

        this.handleHide = () => {
            this.setState({ show: false });
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // if (localStorage.usertoken && localStorage.usertoken != 'undefined') {
        //     const token = localStorage.usertoken;

        //     const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        //     console.log(decoded);
        //     this.setState({
        //         name: decoded.name
        //     })
        // }
    }

    onChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        // console.log("name :", name);
        // console.log("value :", value);
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        let formErrors = this.state.formErrors;

        switch (name) {
            case 'email':
                formErrors.email = emailRegex.test(value) ? '' : "Invalid Email Address";
                break;
            case 'password':
                formErrors.password = value.length < 6 ? 'Minimum 6 character required' : "";
                break;
            default: break;
        }
        this.setState({ formErrors, [name]: value }, () => console.log(this.state));
    }

    logOut(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.removeItem("usertoken");
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }

    onSubmit(e) {

        if (formValid(this.state.formErrors)) {
            this.setState({
                loading: true,
            })
            e.preventDefault();
            const user = {
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
            };

            this.props.loginUser(user).then((res, err) => {
                // console.log(res);
                if (res.Success == '0') {
                    this.setState({
                        loading: false,
                        message: res.Message
                    })
                }
                else {
                    // if (localStorage.usertoken && localStorage.usertoken != 'undefined') {
                    //     const token = localStorage.usertoken;

                    //     const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
                    //     console.log(decoded);
                    //     this.setState({
                    //         name: decoded.name
                    //     })
                    // }
                    this.handleHide();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.error('FORM ERROR - DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE');
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { loading, message } = this.state;
        const { formErrors } = this.state;

        const loginRegLink = (
            <div className="" style={{ display: 'inline-flex' }}>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a onClick={this.handleShow} class="nav-link" style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} >Login&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                {/* <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">SignUp&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li> */}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">AboutUs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">ContactUs</a>
                </li>
            </div>
        );

        const userLink = (
            <div className="" style={{ display: 'inline-flex' }}>
                <li class="nav-item">

                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">{this.props.userlogin.name}</Link>

                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)} className="nav-link">
                        Logout
          </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">AboutUs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">ContactUs</a>
                </li>
            </div>

        );

        return (
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-basic" >
                <Link to="/">
                    <img src={logo} />
                </Link>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100 flex-md-column" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto small mb-2 mb-md-0">
                        {/* <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img className="country-image" src="https://www.countryflags.io/be/shiny/64.png" />&nbsp;English
                        </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li> */}
                        {localStorage.usertoken && localStorage.usertoken != 'undefined' ? userLink : loginRegLink}
                    </ul>

                </div>


                {/* model popup */}
                <Modal
                    show={this.state.show}
                    onHide={this.handleHide}
                    dialogClassName="modal-90w"
                    aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
                    centered
                    size="md"
                >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="example-custom-modal-styling-title text-center">
                            IT Referrals Login
            </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <div class="form-group" id="sampleTableForEmployee">
                            {message !== '' &&
                                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                                    {message}
                                </div>
                            }
                            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                                <div className="row">

                                    <div className="col-md-12">
                                        <div className="input-class-field">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <label htmlFor="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                                                <div className="input-group">
                                                    <span className="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" />
                                                    </span>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="email"
                                                        className='form-control'
                                                        id="email"
                                                        name="email"
                                                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                                        placeholder="anyone@example.com"
                                                        required="required"
                                                        value={this.state.email}
                                                        onChange={this.onChange}
                                                    />
                                                    {formErrors.email && (
                                                        <span className="errorMessage" style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '14px' }}>{formErrors.email}</span>
                                                    )}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <label htmlFor="password"><b>Password</b></label>
                                                <div className="input-group">
                                                    <span className="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" />
                                                    </span>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="password"
                                                        className={formErrors.password.length > 0 ? 'error form-control' : 'form-control'}
                                                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                                        id="password"
                                                        name="password"
                                                        placeholder="********"
                                                        required="required"
                                                        value={this.state.password}
                                                        onChange={this.onChange}
                                                    />
                                                    {formErrors.password.length > 0 && (
                                                        <span className="errorMessage" style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '14px' }}>{formErrors.password}</span>
                                                    )}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <button
                                                    type="submit"
                                                    className="btn btn-primary btn-block pull-right"
                                                    id="btnContactUs"
                                                >
                                                    {loading ? <LoadingSpinner /> : "Login"}
                                                </button><br /><br />
                                                {/* <p className="forgetpassword"><a href="">Forget my password ?</a></p> */}
                                                {/* <p className="signup">Don't have an account? <Link to="/register"> Create Now</Link> </p> */}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <hr />

                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
                {/* end modal popup */}
            </nav >
        )
    }
}

Header.propTypes = {
    loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    userlogin: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userlogin: state.userlogin
});
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { loginUser }
)(Header);
```

My reducer code is -

```
import { SET_CURRENT_USER } from "../Actions/actions";

export default function userlogin(state = [], action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return action.userlogin;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My action code is -

```
// code to login user
export const SET_CURRENT_USER = "SET_CURRENT_USER";

export function loginUser(user) {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/login", {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      })
      .then(res => {
        // Set token to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("usertoken", res.data.token);
        // Decode token to get user data
        const decoded = jwt_decode(res.data.token);
        // Set current user
        dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.data.msg);
      });
  };
}

export function setCurrentUser(userlogin) {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    userlogin
  };
}
```

How to resolve TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined error in header.js file..
How can we make login ?

Comment: Which line is the error from?

Comment: Can not read property 'name' of undefined in {this.props.userlogin.name} in header.js file

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is at here:

```
const userLink = (
            <div className="" style={{ display: 'inline-flex' }}>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    // here, because when render this const will run once and try to find the userLogin.name, but because u haven't login, it doesn't exist
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">{this.props.userlogin.name}</Link>

                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)} className="nav-link">
                        Logout
          </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">AboutUs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">ContactUs</a>
                </li>
            </div>

        );
```

Try to create by function

```
const userLink = () => (
            <div className="" style={{ display: 'inline-flex' }}>
                <li class="nav-item">

                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">{this.props.userlogin.name}</Link>

                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)} className="nav-link">
                        Logout
          </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">AboutUs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">ContactUs</a>
                </li>
            </div>

        );
```

and use it like

```
                        {localStorage.usertoken && localStorage.usertoken != 'undefined' ? userLink() : loginRegLink}
```

hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I would expect `state.userlogin` to start off as an empty array. Since you are setting your reducer to have an initial state of empty array:

```js
export default function userlogin(state = [], action = {}) {}
```

And you link `userlogin` from your store to your component in here:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userlogin: state.userlogin
});
```

However `userlogin` seems to be undefined instead, which makes me believe you haven't mapped your reducer inside your rootreducer correctly. (perhaps you used camelcase there?)

If you have, then perhaps the correct store is not provided to your app or you may have changed the state of `userlogin` to `undefined` after initialisation.